# how to await axios call within .map that is inside of useEffect React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, axios

Inside of my `useEffect` hook I am trying to call an api request that is inside of `.map` but the rest of the function isn't waiting for the response. I've tried making the `.map` `async` but then the rest of the function returns `Promises` what is the correct way of doing this so that my api request can be called and then proceed with the rest of the code?

```
const getData = async (id) => {
    const myData = await api.get(
      '/api/request/id'
    );
    return myData;
  };

useEffect(() => {
  const myData = sampleData.map((item)
    getData(item.id).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data.data);
      return response.data.data
    })
  
  const myThings = myItem.things.map((thing) => {
    if (thing.type === 'sampleType1') {
      return [thing.name, thing.value];
    } else (thing.type === 'sampleType2') {
      return [
        thing.name,
        thing.content.name,
      ];
    }
  });
  setData = {myThings, myData}
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to wait for all those promises to resolve before mapping over them, so this is a great use case for `Promise.all`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    const myData = await Promise.all(sampleData.map((item) =>
      getData(item.id).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.data);
        return response.data.data
      }));
  
    const myThings = myItem.things.map((thing) => {
      if (thing.type === 'sampleType1') {
        return [thing.name, thing.value];
      } else (thing.type === 'sampleType2') {
        return [
          thing.name,
          thing.content.name,
        ];
      }
    });
    setData = {myThings, myData}
  }
  
  fetchData();
}, []);
```